# PHP: Obtain the form "layout" of a custom object via API?

Tags: custom-object, soap-api, php, php-toolkit

*Edit: I may have answered my own question yay! I've just seen  `DescribeLayout` and about to hit that endpoint to see what I get.*

I am currently using the PHP `describeSObject()` method to get a list of all available fields on a custom object.

I have successfully generated a big long basic form on my end to cater for the 'string', 'textarea', 'date' and 'picklist' data types (including `validFor` bit shifting to get correct picklist dependencies on my form).

What I'm struggling to find out though is if there **is a way to get the custom object "layout"** so that I can match my form to the layout of the one in Sales Force?

Even if it's just the order of the fields of how they display in Sales Force? Grouping would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Yep `describeLayout` did the trick.

I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here, surely someone has made a 1-to-1 mapping of Sales Force form with a public PHP form?

[image: describe layout api result]

Yep that's working nicely.

I'll push the code up here once completed for anyone else wanting to duplicate the Sales Force forms within PHP.

[image]